# T-SQL how to modify the value before insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I find that there are only after and instead of triggers in sql server. And it is illegal to modify the values in the inserted pesudo table. Then my problem occurs: If I want to check the data which is going to be inserted into my table, and when the data violates my constraints I should modify these values to default values, how to do it ? How about updateing the values after inserted ? However, if there's no primary key or colum which is unique in my table, how can I locate the row just inserted and then update it ?

Comment: The point of the `INSTEAD OF` triggers is that you can "capture" that operation (e.g. `INSERT`) and then do something *instead of* that normal operation. So you could read out the values, modify them, and then call an `INSERT` inside your `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to insert the modified data

Comment: The problem with that is that if the table structure changes, you need to think of modifying the trigger as well. Oracle instead lets you update the equivalent of the 'inserted' object ('new') which is far more logical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, you can achieve what you're looking for - just read out the data from the `INSERTED` pseudo table, modify it, and insert it into the table

So your trigger would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTrigger ON dbo.YourTable    
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- do the INSERT based on the INSERTED pseudo table, modify data as needed
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ....., ColN)
      SELECT 
          Col1, 2 * Col2, ....., N * ColN
      FROM 
          INSERTED
```

Of course, you could also add e.g. checks in the form of `WHERE` clause to that `SELECT .... FROM INSERTED` statement to e.g. ignore certain rows - the possibilities are endless!