# SQL Server create Triggers on INSERT and SELECT OUTCOME

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I try to create a Trigger that will insert a Unique ID in a table and then get the created ID and use it on the table that "Triggered the trigger"

So I insert some data in my table and then I want the trigger to insert some data in another table (master ID table), it then needs to get the just created ID (auto increment INT) and add this ID to the table ID that the trigger fired on.
I tried quite some different options but it just does not insert the ID and it will give me an error.

Hope you can help me out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[TROidMemoDiaryHeader]
ON  [dbo].[InvoiceDiaryHeader]
FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @TEMP uniqueidentifier, @Lock INT, @Object INT,   @User V     ARCHAR(MAX), @Delay NCHAR(12), @ID INT
SET @TEMP = NEWID()
SET @Lock = '0' --staat geen wijziging meer toe
SET @Object = '5' -- aanduiding bron
SET @User = CURRENT_USER
--SET @Delay = '00:00:00:125' -- Wacht voor een kwart seconde voor     verder te gaan
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
--SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AbstractMBOBase] ([Uid], [OptimisticLockField],     [ObjectType], [User])
    SELECT @TEMP, @Lock, @Object, @User

IF EXISTS (SELECT [Uid] FROM [dbo].AbstractMBOBase WHERE [Uid] = @TEMP)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [InvoiceDiaryHeader](Oid)
    SELECT Oid FROM inserted
    /*
    SELECT * INTO #tmpOID FROM AbstractMBOBase WHERE [Uid] = @TEMP
    UPDATE [dbo].InvoiceDiaryHeader SET Oid = (SELECT a.[Oid] FROM [dbo].[AbstractMBOBase] AS a  
    WHERE [Uid] = @TEMP)
    --CREATE TABLE [dbo].#TempOID()
    --SELECT * INTO #TempOID FROM INSERTED
    */

    /*
    --UPDATE [MemoDiaryHeader]
    SET @ID = (SELECT a.[Oid] FROM [dbo].[AbstractMBOBase] AS a  
    WHERE [Uid] = @TEMP)
    INSERT INTO [MemoDiaryHeader]([Oid])
    SELECT @ID 
    --FROM inserted
    --select [Oid]=i.[Oid] from inserted i
    */
    END
--END
END
GO
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I figured it out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562584/t-sql-how-to-modify-the-value-before-insert 
this is the thred that put me on the right track